# program won't find math.h anymore

Tags: c, linux, linker, libm

After a long time, I downloaded a program I co-developed and tried to recompile it on my Ubuntu Linux 12.04, but it seems it does not find math.h anymore. This may be because something has changed recently in `gcc`, but I can't figure out if it's something wrong in `src/Makefile.am` or a missing dependency:

Download from http://www.ub.edu/softevol/variscan/:

```
tar xzf variscan-2.0.2.tar.gz 
cd variscan-2.0.2/
make distclean
sh ./autogen.sh
make
```

I get:
    [...]

```
gcc -DNDEBUG -O3 -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic  -lm  -o variscan variscan.o statistics.o common.o linefile.o memalloc.o dlist.o errabort.o dystring.o intExp.o kxTok.o pop.o window.o free.o output.o readphylip.o readaxt.o readmga.o readmaf.o readhapmap.o readxmfa.o readmav.o ran1.o swcolumn.o swnet.o swpoly.o swref.o  
statistics.o: In function `calculate_Fu_and_Li_D':
statistics.c:(.text+0x497): undefined reference to `sqrt'
statistics.o: In function `calculate_Fu_and_Li_F':
statistics.c:(.text+0x569): undefined reference to `sqrt'
statistics.o: In function `calculate_Fu_and_Li_D_star':
statistics.c:(.text+0x63b): undefined reference to `sqrt'
statistics.o: In function `calculate_Fu_and_Li_F_star':
statistics.c:(.text+0x75c): undefined reference to `sqrt'
statistics.o: In function `calculate_Tajima_D':
statistics.c:(.text+0x85d): undefined reference to `sqrt'
statistics.o:statistics.c:(.text+0xcb1): more undefined references to `sqrt' follow
statistics.o: In function `calcRunMode21Stats':
statistics.c:(.text+0xe02): undefined reference to `log'
statistics.o: In function `correctedDivergence':
statistics.c:(.text+0xe5a): undefined reference to `log'
statistics.o: In function `calcRunMode22Stats':
statistics.c:(.text+0x104a): undefined reference to `sqrt'
statistics.o: In function `calculate_Fu_fs':
statistics.c:(.text+0x11a8): undefined reference to `fabsl'
statistics.c:(.text+0x11ca): undefined reference to `powl'
statistics.c:(.text+0x11f2): undefined reference to `logl'
statistics.o: In function `calculateStatistics':
statistics.c:(.text+0x13f2): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [variscan] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/avilella/variscan/latest/variscan-2.0.2/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

The libraries are there because this simple example works perfectly well:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -lm
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
        double x = 0.5;
        double result = sqrt(x);
        printf("The hyperbolic cosine of %lf is %lf\n", x, result);
        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's finding the header, but not the library, or at least not the symbols it's looking for. What happens if you try these two commands on your test file? `gcc -DNDEBUG -O3 -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic  -lm  -o test.o -c test.c` and `gcc -DNDEBUG -O3 -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic  -lm  -o test test.o`? Maybe an environment variable is incorrect when running `make`?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error during make.

Comment: @mkb the second command works, the first one fails with this error: `warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘%lf’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat]`

Comment: Try compiling it putting the `-lm` last.  Some linkers process the `-l` flag by looking up all symbols found _up to that point_; others process it by adding it to a list of libraries which are searched at the end.  I can't remember which way `gcc` does it, but if you want your code to be at all portable between compilers, you should assume the more conservative behaviour and put `-lm` last.

Comment: How do I modify `src/Makefile.am` to add `-lm` at the end? If I do it manually, it still doesn't seem to work, so I am with @mkb here that there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library needs to go at the end of the compiler command, as you have in the simple example:

> gcc -DNDEBUG -O3 -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o variscan variscan.o statistics.o common.o linefile.o memalloc.o dlist.o errabort.o dystring.o intExp.o kxTok.o pop.o window.o free.o output.o readphylip.o readaxt.o readmga.o readmaf.o readhapmap.o readxmfa.o readmav.o ran1.o swcolumn.o swnet.o swpoly.o swref.o   statistics.o -lm

From [GCC Link Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

```
-llibrary
-l library
    Search the library named library when linking. 
    (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument
    is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)

    It makes a difference where in the command you write this option;
    the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the
    order they are specified.
    Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o' searches library `z' after file foo.o but
    before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in `z', those functions
    may not be loaded.
```

Comment: moving the `-lm -o variscan` to the end of the line did work, but I don't know how to change this in the `src/Makefile.am` to make it automatic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this simple change would suffice in `Makefile.am`:

```
+variscan_LDADD = -lm
-variscan_LDFLAGS = -lm
```

Comment: Libraries don't belong in `LDFLAGS`. They belong in a separate variable that will go at the **end** of the linker command line, often called `LIBS`. I forget which name automake prefers.